# Jquery this not always selecting this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

I have multiple divs, When the user clicks on the div, it simply animates some text on the div. The problem is that the correct div is selected some of the time, but some of the time it targets the incorrect div.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$('#SpinnerTrue').css('opacity', '0.0');
$( ".GameWrapper .spinnerWrapper" ).click(function() {
    Slide(this, 40);
});
});
function Slide(id, Size)
{
var VidF = $(id).children("#SpinnerFalse");
var VidT = $(id).children("#SpinnerTrue");
var VidV = $(id).children(".LocalVal");

var amount = Size;
if($(VidV).val() == "true")
{
    $( VidF ).animate({ "top": "+="+amount, 'opacity': '1.0'}, "fast" );
    $( VidT ).animate({ "top": "+="+amount, 'opacity': '0' }, "fast" );
    $( VidV ).val('false');
}
else
{
    $( VidF ).animate({ "top": "-="+amount, 'opacity': '0'  }, "fast" );
    $( VidT ).animate({ "top": "-="+amount, 'opacity': '1.0' }, "fast" );
    $( VidV ).val('true');
}
}
```

Comment: What is your html?  Are you sure that it's always the div itself coming in on the function?

Comment: if you provide fiddke that wil be beter

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle also with HTML

Comment: using $(this) is a bit more accurate with jQuery

Comment: Judging from the code, there would be several elements with the id `SpinnerFalse` and `SpinnerTrue`? An id should be unique in the page, or some things won't work properly.

Comment: Sorry, Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/nbwLG/
The strange part is it is working as expected in js fiddle :/

Comment: hey downvoters. this is not four downvotes bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me....

Sample fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/JbFe2/

My html, based on your js structure...

```
<div class="GameWrapper">
    <div class="spinnerWrapper">
        <div id="SpinnerFalse">FALSE</div>
        <div id="SpinnerTrue">TRUE</div>
        <div class="LocalVal">LocalVAL</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would harmonize your naming convention by the way.  Classes usually are all lower case 'game-wrapper'...id should be spinnerFalse.  Don't switch back and forth between SpinnerFalse and spinnerFalse, you'll end up creating problems for yourself.

Comment: KnowHowSolutions, your html actually looks remarkably close to mine. I have multiple spinnerWrapper classes with the same id inside, could that be causing the problem?

Comment: Of course...one id, one element.  Use classes...jsfiddle must be helping you somehow.